# how to know if an estimator is unbiased

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I have some doubt about this excercise, can someone help me?

Let $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be independent identically distributed random variables with p.d.f. $$f(x) = \theta^2 x \exp(-\theta x),$$     with $x>0$.

Is $T(X_1,\dots,X_n)= 1/X_1$ an unbiased estimator of $\theta$?

I know that this estimator is unbiased when $E(X)$ is equal to $\theta$, but how can I find $E(X)$ of an estimator
it's different from $E(X)$ of a random varible ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Can you find the distribution of $1/X_1$?, there is a theorem that talks about functions of random variables that could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

Using the law of the unconscious statistician you get that

$$E[\frac{1}{X}] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$$

Comment: thank you very much for the hint . if I am not wrong this should be an unbiased estimator because the integral between 0 and infinity of this stuff is equal to θ . Then, since the bias is computed as the difference between E(X)- θ this should be an unbiased estimator ? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: yes. you nailed it ! You can [accept the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) then :-)